# Google Chrome Inspect Elements

Tags: html, wordpress, google-chrome, element

I have a quick question which would really help me out, i'm sure it must be simple -- if its possible.

I am developing a wordpress website and using Chrome Inspects to edit the CSS, which i'm fine with. However, when I want edit the html code, I cant find the name of file i am editing on elements. Is there a way to find out the file name?

Hope that makes sense,

All the best,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is on the top right corner of each css property.

Comment: Thank You. That is just the css. What about the HTML file?

Comment: Do you mean the HTML file where the css property is applied?

Comment: Please see screengrab - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzrotBjCEGnlV0wzQ1NtMWVFTkk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I want to find the file where the highlighted code is. Sorry for being a nightmare

Comment: if you are on 'Elements' tab, the file is the current page you are seeing on the browser

Comment: The URL for the current page is www.domainname.co.uk/product/personalized_rose/